# What is the strongest arithmetic theory decidable by a DFA, DPDA or PDA?

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, pushdown-automata, decision-problem, arithmetic

It is [known](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/COURSES/452/F14/ws1stalk.pdf) that WS1S can be decided by a DFA. Is this the strongest arithmetic theory decidable by a DFA? What happens when the automata class is extended to include DPDAs or PDAs?

Comment: Question: how is going from a DFA to a PDA weakening? Aren’t PDAs capable of recognizing more languages, and therefore stronger?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was thinking of "weaker" in a different sense. Question edited.

Comment: The slides you link to do not provide a proof of regularity, and I find the claim that S1S can be decided by DFAs weird. How do you represent infinite sets? This is commonly done with  $\omega$-automata.

Comment: @Shaull Right, it's WS1S that's regular.